# Headphones not working on ASUS n551jm (both Ubuntu and Windows 10)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi, headphones

Please help me. *I can't work without headphones :(*

I have weird issue with my headphones - they do not work in entire laptop (windows and ubuntu). I have dual boot.

That behavior started about two weeks ago. I can't realize what actually happen, i do nothing special - everything as usual.

Whereas speakers works fine on both windows and ubuntu.

Occasionally sound in my headphones returns by random reason and disappear also randomly.

---

This is output of alsa script:
http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=179e2b87b66b9c12c0b9aa2a5a436ed23751b7a9

---

In ubuntu sound settings i see nothing wrong - two options speakers and headphones:
[Ubuntu sound settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ymni5.png)

When i chose speakers sound appear, but when i change it to headphones i hear nothing.

---

I try to resolve that issue by run command below:

```
echo "options snd-hda-intel model=auto" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

I do that command and reboot the system but nothing happen. Still no sound.

I've also installed pavucontrol:
[pavucontrol output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7IDJ.png)

Silence indicator leap but i hear nothing when headphones plugged in.

---

Another thing that i do is to see output of AlsaMixer:

[alsamixer output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmUVW.png)
[alsamixer output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQSm3.png)

Also nothing special, everything in order.

---

Maybe reason of that behavior HDA Intel PCH  and HDA Intel HDMI conflict?

I have two additional displays that connect to laptop through HDMI  - may be here lies the secret.

---

In windows system also there are no headphones sound , by default chosen HDMI sound card. When i try to switch to another intel sound card nothing happen - still there are no sound in headphones but in speakers there are.

Comment: Have you checked your BIOS setting? See if the sound card is still enabled.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to unplug the hdmi kabels restart the notebook and check the audio jack? Because I think your audio jack is busted. I had the same issue with my N550JV. My problem was that I wasn't able to hear anything when the headphones where fully pluged in. You should check if winodws or ubuntu regionize wheter the headphones are pluged in or not.